# Using awk array to compare $NF

Tags: awk

The following command has the following output:

```
[xr-vm_node0_RP0_CPU0:~]$show_snmp_interface_notif -x .*
ifName : Null0                 ifIndex: 1
ifName : MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0   ifIndex: 2
ifName : Loopback0             ifIndex: 5
ifName : Bundle-Ether25        ifIndex: 6
ifName : Bundle-Ether42        ifIndex: 7
ifName : Optics0/0/0/0         ifIndex: 8
ifName : Optics0/0/0/1         ifIndex: 9
...
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/3    ifIndex: 92
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/2    ifIndex: 93
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/1    ifIndex: 94
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/0    ifIndex: 95
ifName : Loopback1             ifIndex: 96
```

I would like to extract the lines where the last column equals any of the numbers below.

```
2  6  7  52  53  54  55  56  57  89  90  91
```

Attempts:
1) Confirmed that above elements were stored and printed via array[i] correctly

```
[xr-vm_node0_RP0_CPU0:~]$show_snmp_interface_notif -x .* | awk 'BEGIN{split("2  6  7  52  53  54  55  56  57  89  90  91",array)}; END {for (i in array) print array[i]}'
2
6
7
52
53
54
55
56
57
89
90
91
```

2) Verified that $NF matches the last column

```
[xr-vm_node0_RP0_CPU0:~]$show_snmp_interface_notif -x .* | awk '{print $NF}'
1
2
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
...
92
93
94
95
96
```

3) Wrote the following awk statement which does not print anything. I suspect the print statement is incorrect. We need to pull out the complete line if the last column matches any of the specified elements in array[i].

```
[xr-vm_node0_RP0_CPU0:~]$show_snmp_interface_notif -x .* | awk 'BEGIN{split("2  6  7  52  53  54  55  56  57  89  90  91",array)}; END {for (i in array); if(array[i]==$NF) { print $i }}'

[xr-vm_node0_RP0_CPU0:~]$show_snmp_interface_notif -x .* | awk 'BEGIN{split("2  6  7  52  53  54  55  56  57  89  90  91",array)}; END {for (i in array); if(array[i]==$NF) { print i }}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove one `;` and `END` to run for loop with every row of stdin. With `;` your for loop has no body.

```
... | awk 'BEGIN{split("2  6  7  52  53  54  55  56  57  89  90  91",array)}; {for (i in array) if(array[i]==$NF) { print }}'
```

Output:

```
ifName : MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0   ifIndex: 2
ifName : Bundle-Ether25        ifIndex: 6
ifName : Bundle-Ether42        ifIndex: 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  num=split("2 6 7 52 53 54 55 56 57 89 90 91",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    b[array[i]]
  }
}
($NF in b)
'   Input_file
```

OR

```
your_command | awk '
BEGIN{
  num=split("2 6 7 52 53 54 55 56 57 89 90 91",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    b[array[i]]
  }
}
($NF in b)'
```

Comment: @user Didn't need to test. Time for one array lookup < for looping all choises or regex.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without array.  (If data comes for another source array my be fine to use).  Should be faster since no loop are involved.

```
your commands | awk '$NF~/^(2|6|7|52|53|54|55|56|57|89|90|92)$/'
ifName : MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0   ifIndex: 2
ifName : Bundle-Ether25        ifIndex: 6
ifName : Bundle-Ether42        ifIndex: 7
```

Comment: @user Normally loops are slower, so If I can avoid it, I do, but depending of the amount of data this can vary. Anyway this is less complicated and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

there's no need to pre-hard-code anything : say if you have a dynamic list of values you wanna include, place them at shell variable `${__}` :

```
    __=''
    for __ in ' 2 8 6  7  52  53  54  55  56  57  89  90  91 ' \
              ' 1 5  9  92 96 ' ; do
       export __
       echo "${input_data}" | mawk "$( mawk -v __="${__}" 'BEGIN {

          printf("%.*sBEGIN { printf(\"\\n\\t [ %s ]\\n" \
                 "\\n\") >> (\"/dev/stderr\") }  /: (%s)$/",
                ($+(OFS = "|") = __)*_, NF = NF, $-_, $-_) }' )" | gcat -b
    done
```

> ```
> input
> ```

```
ifName : Null0                 ifIndex: 1
ifName : MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0   ifIndex: 2
ifName : Loopback0             ifIndex: 5
ifName : Bundle-Ether25        ifIndex: 6
ifName : Bundle-Ether42        ifIndex: 7
ifName : Optics0/0/0/0         ifIndex: 8
ifName : Optics0/0/0/1         ifIndex: 9
...
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/3    ifIndex: 92
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/2    ifIndex: 93
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/1    ifIndex: 94
ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/0    ifIndex: 95
ifName : Loopback1             ifIndex: 96
```

> ```
> output
> ```

```
 [ 2|8|6|7|52|53|54|55|56|57|89|90|91 ]

 1  ifName : MgmtEth0/RP0/CPU0/0   ifIndex: 2
 2  ifName : Bundle-Ether25        ifIndex: 6
 3  ifName : Bundle-Ether42        ifIndex: 7
 4  ifName : Optics0/0/0/0         ifIndex: 8

 [ 1|5|9|92|96 ]

 1  ifName : Null0                 ifIndex: 1
 2  ifName : Loopback0             ifIndex: 5
 3  ifName : Optics0/0/0/1         ifIndex: 9
 4  ifName : HundredGigE0/0/1/3    ifIndex: 92
 5  ifName : Loopback1             ifIndex: 96
```

once you turn on the `gawk` profiler, you can see how a single nested-subshell does wonders :

> ```
> BEGIN { printf("\n\t [ 2|8|6|7|52|53|54|55|56|57|89|90|91 ]\n\n")
>                                            >> ("/dev/stderr")
>
> } /: (2|8|6|7|52|53|54|55|56|57|89|90|91)$/
>
> BEGIN { printf("\n\t [ 1|5|9|92|96 ]\n\n") >> ("/dev/stderr")
>
> }  /: (1|5|9|92|96)$/
> ```

especially for larger inputs, the time spent dynamically generating the code pays itself off multiple times over from speed gains via the newly-hard-coded `regex/constants`, thus avoiding any arrays or loops, while still being able to parameterize input

code itself has been tested on `mawk` `gawk` and `nawk`, and it *should* in theory also work with `busybox awk`